# Fixed div inside container

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a sidebar navigation menu:

```
<div class="container">
    <nav class="panel-nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#about us">About us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contacts">Contacts</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

The width of the container `1500px`. I need to do fixed block `panel-nav` against the right edge. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
.container{
  position:relative;
}
.panel-nav{
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  top:0;
}
```

Code like this in your css.

Comment: While this may be correct, it may be more beneficial to suggest as to *why* this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

**Top right of corder of the browser**

```
.container{
    width: 1500px;
    min-height: 2000px; /* Just added to get scroll */
    background: #eee;
    position: relative;
}
/* Top left of corder of the browser */
.panel-nav{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

**Top right of corder of the wrapper**

```
.container{
    width: 1500px;
    min-height: 2000px; /* Just added to get scroll */
    background: #eee;
    position: relative;
}
.panel-nav{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/shanidkv/j1kwh370/2/)

Comment: The block must be fixed relative to the container. In the first case, it is relatively browser and the second relatively container, but not fixed.

Comment: Make you wrapper position: relative; Absolute position always work based on parent position.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult without the rest of your HTML, and CSS. But you might like to try this

```
.panel-nav {
   float: right;
}
```